# Condition checking when adding array elements

Tags: java, arrays

I want to check the condition when adding array elements as if given input is negative,It should print a message "You have entered invalid mark." else it should return array and perform other tasks.i did this code but i am not getting my answer.help me.

```
static int[] enter_marks(int sub,Scanner s)
{
       
       int [] array = new int[sub];
       for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
           if(!(array[i]<0))
           {
               array[i] = s.nextInt();
            }
           else
           {
            System.out.println("You have entered invalid mark.");
               break;
           }
        }
        return array;
           
}
```

Comment: In your first if-clause you are trying to read values from the array. However, the array doesn't have correct values inserted yet. You're trying to check something that isn't there yet. So what you should do is: (1) get the input from the scanner (2) check if it's negative (3) add it to the array if it is, else print your "invalid mark"

Answer (score 1):

if(!(array[i]<0))

replace the array[i] with s.nextInt().

Comment: That doesn't actually change anything. `array.length` is the same as `sub` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

1. You always return your array but looks like you want to return it only if all numbers are positive;
2. You have to first read input from a scanner, then check if it isn't negative, then decide whether you want it to be added to your array or you want for-loop to break.

```
    static int[] enter_marks(int sub, Scanner s) {
        int[] array = new int[sub];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int input = s.nextInt();
            if (input >= 0) {
                array[i] = input;
            } else {
                System.out.println("You have entered invalid mark.");
                // Either throw an exception or return an empty array
                // if you do not want any previously read values to be returned.
                return new int[0]; // change to `new int[sub]` if you need to return an empty array of sub size
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are checking the array at i before reading, should read before insert actually:

```
int [] array = new int[sub];
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    int c = s.nextInt();
       if(c >= 0)
       {
           array[i] = c;
       }
       else
 ....
```